# Migration of Posts from old Wordpress instalation to new PHP Application

Tags: php, mysql, xml, wordpress, database-migration

On one side I have a really old Wordpress instalation on a Linux machine. Boss wants us to close that machine but we have more than 1200 posts that we can't loose.
On the other hand I have a PHP app that creates Posts (cases) with a Newsroom index, Categories etc.
I want a way to export from Wordpress the Posts (Wordpress lets me export only XML) and import into the app and thus creating all of the existing Posts on the new APP.
I want to underline the fact that the Wordpress XML has other tags than my PHP app has, so I have to fix this also.

Can I do it in a .php page with a import button that posts them into my mysql database, directly?
Does the PHP, MySql verion matter here? I'm running XAMPP on localhost with the lastest PHP, while the app it's written in 7.

Are there any good integration software that can translate the exported XML into the app database?

I tried to create a .php page with a button to import the the XML file but without succes. No additinal info got into the databse.

Here is PHP code that should Parse the XML.

Thank you.
Andro

````
function sanitizeData($data)
{
    return htmlspecialchars_decode(htmlspecialchars(stripslashes(trim($data))));
}

// Function to insert a post into the database
function insertPost($conn, $post)
{
    $postTitle = sanitizeData($post['PostTitle']);
    $categoryId = (int) $post['CategoryId'];
    $subCategoryId = (int) $post['SubCategoryId'];
    $postDetails = sanitizeData($post['PostDetails']);
    $postingDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($post['PostingDate']));
    $updationDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($post['UpdationDate']));
    $isActive = (int) $post['Is_Active'];
    $postUrl = sanitizeData($post['PostUrl']);
    $postImage = sanitizeData($post['PostImage']);
    $viewCounter = (int) $post['viewCounter'];
    $postedBy = sanitizeData($post['postedBy']);
    $lastUpdatedBy = sanitizeData($post['lastUpdatedBy']);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO tblposts (PostTitle, CategoryId, SubCategoryId, PostDetails, PostingDate, UpdationDate, Is_Active, PostUrl, PostImage, viewCounter, postedBy, lastUpdatedBy) VALUES ('$postTitle', $categoryId, $subCategoryId, '$postDetails', '$postingDate', '$updationDate', $isActive, '$postUrl', '$postImage', $viewCounter, '$postedBy', '$lastUpdatedBy')";

    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        echo "Post inserted successfully!<br>";
    } else {
        echo "Error inserting post: " . mysqli_error($conn) . "<br>";
    }
}

// Create a new XML parser
$xmlParser = xml_parser_create();

// Function to handle the start element event
function startElement($parser, $elementName, $attributes)
{
    // Check if the element is "post"
    if ($elementName === 'post') {
        // Insert the post into the database
        insertPost($GLOBALS['conn'], $attributes);
    }
}

// Set the handler functions for start element event
xml_set_element_handler($xmlParser, 'startElement', null);

// Set the options for the XML parser
xml_parser_set_option($xmlParser, XML_OPTION_CASE_FOLDING, 0);

if (isset($_POST["import"])) {
    $xmlFile = $_FILES["xmlFile"]["tmp_name"];

    if (file_exists($xmlFile)) {
        $handle = fopen($xmlFile, "r");

        // Read and parse the XML file chunk by chunk
        while ($data = fread($handle, 4096)) {
            xml_parse($xmlParser, $data, feof($handle));
        }

        fclose($handle);
        xml_parser_free($xmlParser);

        echo "XML file imported successfully!<br>";
    } else {
        echo "XML file not found!<br>";
    }
}

mysqli_close($con);

?>

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="xmlFile" accept=".xml" required>
    <button type="submit" name="import">Import XML</button>
</form>```
````

Comment: Can you share what you tried?  Maybe we could try and fix that

Comment: I'll try, yes.
Sorry, how can I post code?

Comment: Just edit your question.  If you put three backticks before and after your code it will format it nicely

Comment: I migrate data a lot, from many different CMSs. My recommendation is to export to a format that you are comfortable with, and that has all of the fields you want. My personal preference is JSON, but XML is fine, too. Don't use the built-in stuff, just make a simple PHP script that calls `get_posts()` with what you want to get, and you can use `get_post_meta()`, `get_post_taxonomies()`, `wp_get_post_terms()` and such to get the data. Once you've got your own export, just reverse the process into your system.

Comment: What happened when you ran your PHP script?  Did you see an error?  (NB you should probably use bound parameters rather than passing strings directly into SQL statements - it will make your import safer and faster)

Comment: @RobEyre
it just says "No file chosen", after I select the XML file from my PC location.

Comment: Instead of using '.xml' have you tried `accept="text/xml"` on your file upload field?